# Putting a vector of pairs in an unordered_map vs a map

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

So consider this code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<vector<pair<int,int>>,int> mp ;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        vector<pair<int,int>> v ;
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
            v.push_back(make_pair(j,2*j)) ;
        mp[v] = i ;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I'm doing here is creating an `unordered_map` with keys of the type `vector<pair<int,int>>`. As you can see [here](https://code.hackerearth.com/943dc8c), this raises an error.

But when I change this `unordered_map` to just a `map`, [this error doesn't occur anymore](https://code.hackerearth.com/99841bW).
That is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<vector<pair<int,int>>,int> mp ;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        vector<pair<int,int>> v ;
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
            v.push_back(make_pair(j,2*j)) ;
        mp[v] = i ;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Works well.

So what is with `unordered_map`s and putting `vector`s in them as keys? What is going on here?

Comment: ```85:34: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > >) (const std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >&)```is not this error message clear enough ? just read what requirement for key class has ```map``` and ```unordered_map```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://thispointer.com/map-vs-unordered_map-when-to-choose-one-over-another/. The difference between map and unordered map is the way keys are handled internally. From the log, it appears that the hash function for the key vector<pair<int,int>> is missing.

Comment: Why on earth would you ever want to use a vector of pairs of ints as a key?

Comment: `map` is using operator `<` for vectors to define an ordering. `unordered_map` requires a hash value to put the key in an appropriate bucket but since you haven't specified it, it's throwing an error.

Comment: Unrelated, but possibly helpful for the future: [Why should I not #include<bist/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Also please post error messages directly in the question to save us some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate a little on this:
For [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

> std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys.Keys are sorted by using the comparison function Compare. [...] Maps are usually implemented as red-black trees.

Said *"function Compare"* is a template parameter with default value `std::less<Key>`. So a map needs to compare values using `<` to sort them into the red-black-tree. `std::vector` supports (such a comparison)[https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp].

[std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) on the other hash requires a hash-function to put keys into hash buckets. The used hash function is a template parameter with a default value of `std::hash<Key>`.

`std::hash` has only an overload for `vector<bool>`, not for any generic vector. Unless you provide a custom hash function, the unordered_map has no way of computing a hash for the keys, that's what the errors message tells you too.